# Pulling Vendors' ACH Information out of Acumatica using Contract-based APIs

Tags: acumatica

Is it possible to pull vendors' ACH information (Account #, Routing #) out of Acumatica using Contract-based APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Being able to pull ACH Account# and Routing# would be a rather risky security hole of the system. Measures are put into place to explicitly encrypt that data and assert that this cannot be done through the Contract or Soap API.
I am going to venture an answer and say that it cannot be done.